# Is it safe to use PHP uniqid for filenames? Will they always be unique?

Tags: php

I want to use PHPs `uniqid()` function to create a filename for image upload.

There will be only one person uploading images and they can only upload one at a time. I don't care that the filename can be reverse engineered to get the time because it's just a filename.

Is uniqid 100% unique for my use case?

Comment: Have you read the warning on the documentation page of this function on PHP.net? "Warning

This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value. Since most systems adjust system clock by NTP or like, system time is changed constantly. Therefore, it is possible that this function does not return unique ID for the process/thread. Use more_entropy to increase likelihood of uniqueness."

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like below:

```
md5(rand(1,1000000).uniqid(mt_rand(), true))
```

This code piece had already increased uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use time() function in this case

```
$uniqueFilename=time().uniqid(rand());
```

Or like this one

```
$originalFileName = myimage.png
$uniqueFilename=time().$originalFileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `uniqid()` will always be unique *in your case* because you allow only one person and one upload at the same time. This will work because `uniqid()` is generated based on the system time.

You could also use `uniqid(rand(), true)` to generate a more random filename or `md5();` to encrypt your filename.